# How to improve perfomance using multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, message

I've got a program which receives string messages from other applications and parses them using VCL.
Messages are sent as follows:

```
AtomId := GlobalAddAtom(PChar(s));
SendMessage(MyProgramHandle, WM_MSG, 0, AtomID);
GlobalDeleteAtom(AtomID);
```

My program receives this message, parses it for some time, and then returns control to an application.
It takes time to parse one message so perfomance of other applications worsens.

One possible solution is to create form with the same caption and the same class in other thread, and rename class of main form.
But as far as I know it isn't recommended to create forms in threads.

So, what are possible ways to improve perfomance?

Comment: Why do you want create another form? just receive the message and then do the process in a thread.

Comment: I have to process message using VCL. I parse this string and put the result into a grid. Message is sent to the form with the specified caption and class.
If I process message in the main thread, then the applications wait for returning control.

Comment: Make sure that the threading is the bottleneck. When adding large amounts of data to cells in a Grid, after every update a repaint is invoked. Stringgrid.Cols[i]/Rows[i].Beginupdate before and endupdate after updating your data prevents this and will give a big performance increase. I use a custom component where you can basically use grid.beginupdate/endupdate.

Comment: @Pieter even if the drawing happens in zero time, the main VCL thread will still be the main bottleneck for clients which use this thread to post their messages. If there are many clients, the user interface will become unresponsive, and the clients will block each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that both the receiving of the messages and the VCL operations are done in the **same thread** (the main VCL thread)? And so the receiving and processing are serialized and as result the senders are blocked while your app is busy filling the grid? Then I can understand that you ask for a way to move the receiving to a different window message loop.

So I would create a window (not a VCL form) only for the purpose to receive messages and use its message loop to add message to a queue. So you only need to find this (non-VCL) window and SendMessage to its handle. In the VCL thread, a Timer could fetch the next "n" messages and add them to the grid.

Answer (score 6):

The typical approach would be to create a worker thread (or a pool of worker threads). The main thread will continue to receive the messages, but instead of parsing them it will just add them to a queue (a linked list, for example).

The worker thread takes the first element in the queue and processes it. When done it goes back to the queue to get the next element.

Since the queue is a shared resource between multiple threads you have to control access to it. A mutex will ensure that only one thread gets access to the queue at any given time.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
During processing I have to place results in a grid. So, while the main thread is placing results in a grid, it can't receive messages.

Comment: What do you mean by processing? Is this something else you did not describe in your question? All the processing you indicated should be moved to the worker thread(s). The main thread will just take care of the GUI (if you have one) and of adding messages to the queue when they arrive. You do not want the main thread to do heavy work, think of the main thread as the controller, it just sets everything up so that the workers can do the job.

Comment: Processing means parsing string and place results into a grid.
I want control to be returned as fast as possible. 
Placing into a grid runs in the main thread, and while my program is placing smth, it can not receive messages, so control could not be returned immediately.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: As I said before, the worker threads do the heavy work. If you need to update the GUI, then the worker thread should communicate with the main thread and request a GUI update (which should be quick). The main thread cannot block for long periods of time, move everything except the most basic operations to the worker threads and you will be fine.

Comment: In this case, the worker thread has to be the main thread, as it is VCL work which has to done. So it can not be moved to background.

Comment: I don't know Delphi, so I may be missing something, but I see two different steps here. One is the parsing of these messages, this is a time consuming task that has nothing to do with VCL, so it can be moved to a worker thread. The other is the updating of a grid with the results of the parsing, this is a GUI operation, so you have to do it in the main thread, but since updating a GUI component is quick this isn't a problem.

Comment: The key is that the message receive part requires a window handle, so a simple thread will not be work. The soultion could even be split up into three logical units - receive, process, visualize, using a thread safe queue in between